# How to check if two value of dictionaries exist within the same index?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've got a Python list of dictionaries, as follows:

```
lists = [
{"from":'Alice', "to":'Jack'},
{"from":'Bob', "to":'Mike'}
]
```

And I want to check if `'Alice' and 'Jack'` or `'Bob' and 'Mike'` is already exist in lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that actually works:

```
names = set((pair['from'], pair['to']) for pair in lists)
if ('Alice', 'Jack') in names or ('Bob', 'Mike') in names:
    print('the pair exists in the list')
```

Comment: yeah! this work perfectly, thank you very much and how can i get lists index of ('Alice', 'Jack') or ('Bob', 'Mike')

Comment: Then you'll have to use a `list`, not a `set`. Like this: `names = [(pair['from'], pair['to']) for pair in lists]; names.index(('Alice', 'Jack'))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
values = [list(i.values()) for i in lists]
if ['Alice', 'Jack'] in values or ['Bob', 'Mike'] in values:
    print("All of them are there")
```

If you want the indexes:

```
>>> lists = [{"from":'Alice', "to":'Jack'}, {"from":'Bob', "to":'Mike'}]
>>> values = [list(i.values()) for i in lists]
>>> if ['Alice', 'Jack'] in values or ['Bob', 'Mike'] in values:
        print("All of them are there")


All of them are there
>>> print(values.index(['Alice', 'Jack']))
0
>>> print(values.index(['Bob', 'Mike']))
1
>>>
```

Comment: This is incorrect, `values` is not a list of _tuples_, it looks like this: `['Jack', 'Alice', 'Mike', 'Bob']`, and the `if` condition doesn't make sense, that's not how `or` works. I can't understand how this was accepted!

Comment: @Black Thunder Thank you!!, that is help. another question how can i get index of values that i looking for?

Comment: @Kaow all the values are in the list `a`.

Comment: @Kaow this code is completely wrong, it works with your example just by chance!

Comment: @BlackThunder your syntax is wrong, your data is wrong. Test your code with `lists = []` and it'll still print `"All of them are there"`, which is false.

Comment: i just saw a mistake, it always get values if some of those word exist in lists, so it not my answer that i looking for.

Comment: Cool! but still... sometimes your solution might not work, because the order in which `values()` returns the elements is not **guaranteed** to be the same in which they appear when the dict was created.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez It returns the values in the same order.

Comment: @Kaow Did you try with the updated code? What does it say?

Comment: @Black Thunder yes i did, but it just not print out.

Comment: @Kaow Have you tested that on repl?

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in lists.items():
  if key == 'Alice' and value == 'Jack':
    return true
```

is that what your looking for? obviously would add another if clause to check if your other condition is met.

Comment: This is not what OP is asking